# CSS Dropdown menu help

Tags: css, xhtml, drop-down-menu

Can someone tell me why the CSS dropdown menu (rollover "Software Solutions") works here :

http://deltaassocc.web704.discountasp.net/temp/page-works.html

but not here:

http://deltaassocc.web704.discountasp.net/temp/page.html

This has been driving me crazy!  I'm using Firefox 3.0.10.  Please help..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an awful lot of knowledge built into a CSS menu to cover different browser versions and so on. My advice is don't do this yourself. Get a prebuilt one like suckerfish (or one of the many variants).

Alternatively you can use a Javascript based solution like superfish as suggested here.

**Note:** if you need to support IE6 then you'll be using Javascript for that browser anyway as it doesn't support the :hover pseudo-element on anything other than anchors.

Answer (score 1):

Because you are loosing focus on the parent element. On the second one, there are more elements below and when the dropdown extends it goes under the content container - you move your mouse down and it's over the text content container, not over the menu container no more.

Install [web developer toolbar](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/60) and outline box elements, you will see that.

Google for jquery dropdown menu or other javascript-framework based solutions, they'll work fine and cross-browser, unless you're doing it just for self-education.

Answer (score 0):

The pages look the same in IE8 and Firefox. The menu drops down but doesn't look at that great. If your using JQUERY SuperFish is a really good cs-menu.

Comment: I'm still working on it, see how it works on the first on and not the second one, that is my question.  Thanks for the critique though.